# Saving multiple rows along with Parent table

Tags: php, laravel, oop

In my app i have a Payers table which hasMany relationship with Spouses in the Model. I want to be able to add several Spouses to a client in situation where they have more than one spouse while saving their details.
For that purpose I created a Livewire component Spouses with code below.This code allows me to add new form group for each Spouse the Payer has.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Livewire\Component;
class Spouses extends Component
{
    public $spouses = [];
    public function increments()
    {
        $this->spouses[] =count($this->spouses)+1;
    }   
    public function remove($index){
unset($this->spouses[$index]);
    }  
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.spouses');
    }
}
```

The form is on the component page (spouses.blade.php) with the following codes

```
<div>
    <div>
        <span wire:click ="increments" class="btn btn-defaults fa fa-plus padding:2 py-1 cursor:pointer text-success"> Click to Add Spouse(s)</span>
    </div>
       @foreach($spouses as $spouse)
       <div class="col-md-10 d-flex">
              
{!! Form::text('spouse_name', '',array(
            'class' => 'form-control col-3',
            'id' => 'spouse_name',
            'placeholder' => 'Spouse name',
        ))  !!}
        {!! Form::text('spouse_dob', '',array(
            'class' => 'form-control col-3',
            'id' => 'spouse_dob',
            'placeholder' => 'Spouse Age',
        ))  !!}
        {!! Form::text('spouse_emplbiz_add', '',array(
            'class' => 'form-control col-3',
            'id' => 'spouse_emplbiz_add',
            'placeholder' => 'Work Address',
        ))  !!}
        {!! Form::text('spose_income', '',array(
            'class' => 'form-control col-3',
            'id' => 'spose_income',
            'placeholder' => 'Gross Income',
        )) !!}

        <span class="btn btn-defalt fa fa-times text-danger padding:2" 
        wire:click="remove({{$loop->index}})"></span>
        
    </div>
        @endforeach
 </div>
</div>
```

And finally i imported it to my Payers creation page using the @livewire('spouses').

However after filling the form and adding like three Spouses for each client Only one row is added into the Spouses database.

I will appreciate a careful analysis of my codes to tell me how to ensure that all the spuses record save as the Payers details is saving

My PayerController store method code is shown below

```
public function store(CreatePayerRequest $request)
    { 
        $input = $request->all();
        $payer = $this->payerRepository->create($input);
        {   
           $spouses = new Spouse();
            $input = $request->all();
            foreach($spouses as $spouse){
             $spouses->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $spouses->payer_id = 1;
                $spouses->spouse_occupation='NA';
                $spouses->spouse_name = $input['spouse_name'];
                $spouses->spouse_dob = $input['spouse_dob'];
                $spouses->spouse_emplbiz_add = $input['spouse_emplbiz_add'];
                $spouses->spose_income = $input['spose_income'];
                $spouses->save();
              }
               Flash::error('Taxpayers record not saved');
                return redirect(route('payers.index'));
```

Note that i tried moving the line
$spouses = new Spouse();
into the foreach loop but it gave me Undefined variable: spouses

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach loop inside the php script is looping over `$spouses`, but this variable only holds 1 freshly created Spouse.

Your code is hard to read, since inside your foreach loop you are again using `$spouses` but with a different meaning.

Your foreach loop should loop over the spouses that come in from your form, so it should loop over for example `$request->input('spouce_name')` or something.

But this requires array data to come in and I think your form data is not coming in correctly, since inside your blade you create a foreach loop, but you create multiple form elements with the same name. Your form will then only use the last value. If you change the input names to array values, it should work, so change `spouce_name` to `spouce_name[]`